# putting a div below an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, tabs

I've got a problem with putting a div below an absolute positioned element which doesn't have a fixed height. The codes are too long to paste here, so I'm posting the link to the html file instead; http://infomailer.kotra.or.kr/20141127/oisy.html

I need to move that 'dd' to the bottom of the document, not using margin or absolute-positioning because this document is to be read by mobile devices as well. What should I do to keep the main structure of tab module and fix the problem?

Comment: Try to create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7vyx6Lro/ here. thank you for the tip.

Comment: Absolute positioned div's are out of layout. So, you can't keep any element relative to that element unless if the element is the child of the absolute element. So, it is better to calculate the height of the absolute positioned element using javascript and layout the `dd` element as necessary.

Comment: thank you but i can't use javascript but only css on this document. maybe i should change the whole structure to solve this problem.